# Modify minimum password length in Laravel Breeze

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, passwords, breeze

I am trying to apply the Session Startup Module with Laravel Breeze, but I have a problem.
For security, Breeze prevents the password from being shorter than 8 characters, but on my website it will only be entered with 4 characters... Could someone tell me where I can change this?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit

```
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisteredUserController.php

// change

Rules\Password::defaults()

// to

Rules\Password::defaults()->min(4)
```

You can read more about the Password Validation Rule Object here: https://laravel-news.com/password-validation-rule-object-in-laravel-8